# xhr status in combination with loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write the url of the valid `images` (the images that exist) in the `html` page.
This is the list of input images, added in the variable `urls`:
The urls are urls of existing and non existing google product icons, as example

```
var urls = [
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chart-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/docs-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/drive-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/googlemail-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/dropbox-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/reader-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/test-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/microsoft-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chat-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/hangouts-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/maps-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/map_maker-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/apple-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/latitude-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/sketchup-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/skymap-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/google_favicon-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/mobile_app-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/mobileapp-32.png",
"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/goggles-32.png"
];
```

To check and write down the images url to the document, I use this:
something that totally works fine when you have permission to https://www.google.com/
so when people want to validate this, use the js console on https://www.google.com/

```
var xhr = {};
for(var i = urls.length; i-- ; i>0){
  xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr[i].open('GET',urls[i]);
  xhr[i].onload = write();
  function write() { 
       document.write(urls[i] + "<br>")
    }
  xhr[i].send(null);
  }
```

Now to only write the valid urls (the urls that include a png icon. So `chart-32.png` is valid, but `dropbox-32.png` is unvalid, I tried this code:

```
var xhr = {};
for(var i = urls.length; i-- ; i>0){
  xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr[i].open('GET',urls[i]);
  xhr[i].onload = write();
  function write() { 
    if(xhr[i].status != 404){
       document.write(urls[i] + "<br>")
       }
    }
  xhr[i].send(null);
  }
```

But for some reason, it gives this error in chrome, only when I restrict it to valid pngs:
    Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? And/or how to fix this?

Comment: I see 2 problems in your code but I don't think any would cause a `InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11` 1. closure issue. 2. setting `.onload` to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax-sync needs no "onload callback".

Adjust this line: `xhr[i].open('GET',urls[i]);`

**Fix:** `xhr[i].open('GET',urls[i], false);` --To avoid bugs

Or replace `document.write` by `document.getElement*` (happen to want to use `async-mode`)

Sync mode Ajax, eg.:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET", "http://www.example.com", false);//Sync mode
    r.send(null);
    if (r.readyState===4 && r.status===200) {
        document.write(**content**);
    }
```

Follow this rule (even if it is not ajax):

- `document.write` with sync-mode.
- `document.getElement*` (`getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName` ...) with ascync-mode.